# Restrict access of angular build files

Tags: angular

I am having a hard time restricting access to angular build files using nginx server, I tries chmoding them but if affects the application performance. I also tried to restrict .js files in the nginx.conf but no luck. Any other way to prevent these? I would like to return 404 with these kind of access.

[image]

Comment: You can't. Anything loaded by the browser is publicly visible one way or another. What are you trying to solve?

Comment: I just want to restrict the contents of generated angular files

Comment: There's obfuscation tools out there, but that's about it. The browser downloads them, does it's magic and displays your app. Anyone who visits your site can inspect and see the source code.